# Herkunft von "alles Wotscha?"

Tags: etymology

Ich habe in Heidelberg sicher hundertmal gehört:

> Hey, alles wotscha?

Es heißt wohl "alles klar?". Ich kann mir das nicht recht erklären. Weder "what ya" im Englischen, noch das "wotscha, wotscha" der Almbauern erhellen mir den Zusammenhang. Ist das irgend ein Familienslang?

Comment: In der Harry-Potter-Serie ist _wotcher_ der von Nymphadora Tonks bevorzugte Gruß. Ich weiß aber nicht, wie das in der deutschen Übersetzung wiedergegeben wird und/oder ob die Heidelberger Harry Potter auch nur im Original gelesen haben.

Comment: @chirlu: _»Wotcher,« she said, »we're here to see Arthur Weasley.«_ wurde übersetzt als _»Hallo«, sagte sie, »wir sind hier, um Arthur Weasley zu besuchen.«_  (Harry Potter und der Orden des Phoenix)

Comment: @chirlu, formulieren Sie es doch als Antwort, denn da kommt es offenbar her!

Answer (score 12):

Ich vermute, du meinst *Roger* ([[ˈrɔdʒər]](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger) oder [[ˈrɔd͜ʃɐ]](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/roger)). *Roger* kommt ursprünglich aus dem Funkwesen und bedeutet: "(Nachricht erhalten und) verstanden!".
Umgangsprachlich bedeutet es: "In Ordnung!" oder "Einverstanden!" ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/roger)).

> Alles Roger? =  Alles klar? Alles in Ordnung?
>
> Roger, Roger! =  Ja, alles klar! = Ja, alles in Ordnung! = "OK, (ich bin) einverstanden"

Zur Verbreitung von *Roger* in Deutschland: In Berlin habe ich *Roger* noch nie gehört, in Baden-Württemberg hingegen höre ich das öfters.